# Text Size Slider with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, fonts, scope, font-size

I'm trying to change the font and the font size of an exact text, I got the changing the font part and changing the size but to two different texts. How can I apply both functions to on text.

This is my html

```
<div ng-controller="StylesCtrl">
                    <select ng-model="font" ng-options="font as font.label for font in fonts" ng-change="change(font)"></select>
                    <h3><font face="{{selectedFont}}">Text Is</font></h3>
                </div>
                <text-size-slider min="12" max="24" unit="px" value="18"></text-size-slider>
                <div>Font Size Slider</div>
```

This is my script file

```
(function () {
angular.module('appBuilderApp').controller("StylesCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.fonts = [
       {
          value: 'Arial',
          label: 'Arial'
        },
        {
          value: 'Tahoma',
          label: 'Tahoma'
        }
    ];
    $scope.selectedFont = '';
    $scope.change = function (option) {
       $scope.selectedFont = option.value;
    }
});

angular.module('appBuilderApp').directive('textSizeSlider', ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div class="text-size-slider"><span class="small-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: min + unit }">A</span> <input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}" ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}" /> <span class="big-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: max + unit }">A</span></div>',
      scope: {
        min: '@',
        max: '@',
        unit: '@',
        value: '@',
        step: '@'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.textSize = scope.value;
        scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
          $document[0].body.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
})();
```

please help me to apply both the functions to one text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this to work, I boiled down the code a bit and tried to make more use of built in Angular directives, as well as some HTML5 features. Here's a working version of your code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="StylesCtrl">
    <select ng-options="font for font in fonts" ng-model="text.font"></select>
    <h3 ng-style="{'font-family': text.font, 'font-size': text.size + 'px'}">Text Is</h3>
    <input min="12" max="24" ng-model="text.size" type="range">
    <div>Font Size Slider</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("appBuilerApp", [])
    .controller("StylesCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.fonts = [
            "Arial",
            "Tahoma"
        ];

        $scope.text = {
            font: "Arial",
            size: 18
        };
    });
})()
```

The major changes here are that I'm using a range input instead of a custom directive for the slider. If you need support for IE9 and below, there are polyfills you can use to help you automatically generate range inputs.

Secondly, I'm using the `ngStyle` directive instead of changing styles manually. This is a typical mindset change needed when moving over to Angular - thinking data bindings before event listeners.

Lastly I'm making more use of the `ngModel` directive, which is what binds the value of different inputs in the DOM to data variables. As a rule of thumb, you should always try to bind input values with `ngModel` and then use other directives in other places where you want to apply that value in some way, rather than use `ngChange` to listen for change events.